# SimpleXML parsed response from curl apostrophe issue

Tags: parsing, utf-8, simplexml

so my issue is when I parse an xml response from curl, for some reason the apostrophe characters that I get from simplexml are some weird character. eg:

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);

$xml->description ouputs something like:

> Having agreed to become the Kingâ€™s Hand, Ned leaves Winterfell

Comment: Is whatever you're viewing it in set to interpret it as UTF-8? If not, change settings in your console, browser, or editor to display it as UTF-8.

Comment: Erm, the xml shows the proper characters from the response of the page. However when I parse it using simplexmlelement I think that's where it changes.

Answer (score 0):

SnowInferno is right, nothing has changed. It's just the declared encoding on *your* page is not UTF-8, but Windows-1252. Declare UTF-8 for your page and it will work:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);

$xml->description ouputs something like:
```